# Bypass content restrictions for wkwebview content

Tags: ios, wkwebview, parental-control

we are developing a learn to read app which is based on web technologies and therefore runs in a wkwebview in our native iOS app. The wkwebview is subject to parental controls setting when a parent chooses to restrict all web content. It doesn't matter if the app is allowed when web content is restricted. So is there way to bypass those parental restrictions as our app is already allowed?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35321496/does-wkwebview-implement-parental-control, but that one has no answer.

Comment: I dont really think its a duplicate as its not asking the same question. I know that PC is applied on the webview but I would like to disable it as the app itself is already subject to parental control. The web content we are displaying is sandboxed and its not possible to browse the entire web in our webview.